# Will the C# compiler optimize variable away?

Tags: c#, multithreading, compiler-optimization

This is a follow-up to my post, [Is this a correct implementation of a concurrent observable collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974278/is-this-a-correct-implementation-of-a-concurrent-observable-collection).

In that post I have a custom class that implements a generic concurrent observable list, including an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`. This was the original code:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    var localSnapshot = _snapshot; //create local variable to protect enumerator, if class member (_snapshot) should be changed/replaced while iterating
    return ((IEnumerable<T>)localSnapshot).GetEnumerator();
}
```

With `_snapshot` being a private `Array` field that is rebuilt using a `lock()` whenever the actual inner collection (`List<T> _list`) is modified.

But now I think the `localSnapshot` variable is not required at all, the code should be:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<T>)_snapshot).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Because `localSnapshot` is simply assigned a reference to the same address that `_snapshot` references. `GetEnumerator` doesn't care (and cannot tell) which variable was used (and will for its own use, of course, create yet another variable that references the same array).

If my above assumption is correct, I wonder, if the compiler would optimize the variable away? Then the resulting code would be identical. Or, if not: could copying the reference theoretically even be "harmful", because the copy will be less up-to-date than it could be (another thread could refresh `_snapshot` after the copy was made, but before `GetEnumerator` is called)? And, is this "side-effect" the reason the compiler does not optimize the code - because optimizations are to be "side-effect-free"?

Comment: To reliably answer this, you will need to test this out for your self, The Language Compiler, or most likely the Jitter may just well optimize this away.. If you find your self asking these questions, Check the IL in release mode, also you may want to use https://sharplab.io/ or other tools to check the asm

Comment: In this case, the optimization will be done by the compiler. Both versions of the same code will produce the same IL There is functionally no difference between those two code snippets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two versions of the code will produce the same result after compilation. As TheGeneral pointed out in the comments, a good way to make sure is to check on [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/).

Note that this is true only if you compile in Release mode. If you compile in Debug mode, then the compiler will assume you might need the intermediary variable for debugging purpose and won't optimize it.

> could copying the reference theoretically even be "harmful", because the copy will be less up-to-date than it could be (another thread could refresh _snapshot after the copy was made, but before GetEnumerator is called)

This would be the case if you had some code executing between `var localSnapshot = _snapshot;` and `return ((IEnumerable<T>)localSnapshot).GetEnumerator()`. In that situation the optimization would not have been possible. Otherwise, in both cases you're reading the value and directly using it. There is no difference of "freshness" between the two versions of the code.